# Как убрать отступы вокруг содержимого при вызове объекта InternetExplorer в VBS(см картинку ниже)

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript

Делаю вызовом InternetExplorer.Application окно(см картинку ниже), там отступы вокруг содержимого окна - как их убрать

```html
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

ie.Navigate "about:blank"
ie.document.title = "Контроль учетных записей пользователей Windows - Доступ к "
ie.ToolBar        = False
ie.Resizable      = False
ie.StatusBar      = False
ie.Width          = 500
ie.Height         = 500
ie.Top            = 290
ie.Left           = 710

Set style = ie.document.CreateStyleSheet()
style.AddRule "margin", "0px"
style.AddRule "padding", "0px"
Set style = Nothing

Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4 : WScript.Sleep 100 : Loop

ie.document.body.innerHtml = "<p style='background-color:#fcc534; width:100%; margin:0px; padding:10px;'>Разрешить PascalABC.exe вносить изменения на данном компьютере?</p>" _
  & "<p>Имя программы:  <span style='margin-left:80px'>PascalABC.exe</span></p>" _
  & "<p>Проверенный издатель: <b style='margin-left:30px'>Неизвестно</b></p>" _
  & "<p>Источник файла: <span style='margin-left:80px'>Жесткий диск компьютера</span></p>" _
  & "<p><input type='text' id='userinput' placeholder='Пароль'>" _ 
  & "<p><input type='hidden' id='OK' name='OK' value='0'>" 
ie.Visible = True
ie.document.all.userinput.focus

Do While ie.document.all.OK.value = 0 : WScript.Sleep 100 : Loop

If ie.document.all.OK.value = 1 Then
 Set shell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 shell.run"kill.bat"
Else
 Set shell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 shell.run"kill.bat"
End If
```

Вот это:

```html
Set style = ie.document.CreateStyleSheet()
style.AddRule "margin", "0px"
style.AddRule "padding", "0px"
Set style = Nothing
```

Не работает, хотя если там, к примеру, фон менять - он меняется. а отступы - нет. Помогите пожалуйста
[image: Отступы выделены на изображении]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильно:

```html
Set style = ie.document.CreateStyleSheet()
style.AddRule "body", "margin:0px"
style.AddRule "body", "padding:0px"
Set style = Nothing
```

Вот и все решение)